# $.each but only one of my variables is being used?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the colors of of my map if below 35, it goes through and gets Alaska but stops after that. Should it not be looping through and assigning a color to each one that is below 35? I'm not getting why this isn't working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(states, function(i, stateData) {
        losingState = stateData.Abb;
        currentState = this;

        if (currentState.wins < 35) {
            var testState = currentState.Abb;
            var fillColor = "red";
            $('#map').brett({
                stateSpecificStyles: {
                    [testState]: {
                        fill: fillColor
                    },
                },
                'mouseoverState': {
                    'HI': function(event, data) {
                        //return false;
                    }
                },

                'click': function(event, data) {
                    $('#alert')
                        .text('Click ' + data.name + ' on map 1')
                        .stop()
                        .css('backgroundColor', '#ff0')
                        .animate({
                            backgroundColor: '#ddd'
                        }, 1000)
                        .append('<p><strong>' + currentState.name + '</strong> has a winning percentage of <span class="percentage">' + currentState.wins + '%</span></p>');
                }
            });
        } else {
            var fillColor = "green";
            var winningState = currentState.Abb;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle please?

Comment: It's a library I'm using so it's hard to provide that.

Comment: Do you have this on a server ?? as it's hard to understand this without an example

Comment: @mrid sadly I don't. I'm not sure how else to show this I think the issue is that it's selecting the #map for each state.